# Google Sheets: Swap X and Y Axis in Chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I am trying to illustrate the twist in a sail using a chart, showing the effect of various twist amounts.
[image: Google Sheets data]
However, try as I might, I cannot swap the x and y axis! The cells B3:B8 are the height going up the sail, where the measurements were taken, and should be the y-axis.

The columns C:V are series, which are different sets of measurements taken at the various heights up the sail, with the degree of twist as the series' values. This is what I have:
[image]
I've also tried to create the chart from Transpose()d data (swapped rows <-> cols) but ended up with the same chart! The "Height" is supposed to be the Y-axis, and the values ("Degrees") the X-axis.

I must be missing something obvious, but Google is not my friend today. I have created a sample Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qM1LLI6cHe27T65KiHM51fVyGuxx3rLZL4hkMcTAAM/edit#gid=0) if anyone can help. MTIA.

Comment: did you try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWc3B.png ?

Comment: If you are referring to "Switch rows/columns",  yes, I tried that but it changes the series from using the columns to using the rows - which is incorrect.

Comment: any better? https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1CtC.png

Comment: From your question it looks like you want the lines to run vertically, else the chart will just draw straight lines from left to right because the height values are constant, e.g. 26.50. Is this the intended output?

Comment: @player0, looks like you're trying everything I did! Still not what is intended - the Y-axis should be the heights (Foot of Sail... to... Head of Sail), and the values should be on the X-axis.

Comment: @Carlos, that is correct.  It's like looking at the sail from the stern of a boat, the zero value on the x-axis is the mast, and shows how far the sail is 'twisted' in degrees, vs the height of the sail on the y-axis. So the lines run vertically - with a bit of a curve.

Comment: PS: If you turn the chart I created (see img in Question) anti-clockwise 90 degrees, that's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is *not possible* to define the Y-Axis to a specific range for Smooth Line Chart, in fact, the only way this can be defined is by using Bar Chart.

As a **workaround**, you can use Bar Chart to define the Y-Axis like this:

[image]

Please note that it only looks best when displaying one or two series, the bars would look squished when more series are added.

As for the original intention of defining Y-axis for Line Charts, or a completely new type of chart, you can file a feature idea request here:

[How To Submit a Feature Idea Request](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)

[Google Workspace Feature Idea Request Link](https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/googleworkspace-feature-ideas)

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I think I was heading towards the same conclusion!   I'm a novice when it comes to charts, otherwise I suppose I would have known that.  Appreciate you taking the time to look into it. Cheers, Max